# How to get application name in AWS Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

Using Lambda function associated with AWS Cognito service I can pool the id of application registered in Cognito user pool by calling ${event.callerContext.clientId} inside the Lambda. Is there a way to pool application name instead? Something like ${event.callerContext.clientName //OR// applicationName}?

Comment: You can use/call [DescribeUserPoolClient](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeUserPoolClient.html) or same SDK API from the programming language your are using for your AWS Lambda

Comment: I'm using CustomMessage_SignUp build-in trigger which is a part of Cognito signup flow that allows for customizing verification email. I'm not using SDK at this point.